# Can my Connected App be forced to use the stored redirect_uri?

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

I would like to use the Amazon Alexa voice service to create a voice interface for Salesforce. But I've run into problems.

I am reading here:

http://blog.enree.co/2015/12/salesforce-amazon-echo-integrate-alexa.html

and I read:

"unfortunately when linking accounts Amazon's Alexa Skills page doesn't sends to the login page the redirect_uri parameter that is mandatory for successfull Salesforce OAuth process completion."

There might be a variable name conflict, since both SalesForce and Amazon use "redirect_uri" in the URLs they use as part of their Oauth process.

On the Amazon side, I believe I've done all I can to set this up.

I've gone to my Developer Portal:

https://developer.amazon.com/edw/home.html#/skill/amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.b9ae614ad/info

(Obfuscated for security)

Under "Account Linking or Creation", under "Domain List", I whitelisted this domain:

salesforce.com

If I take my iPhone and open the Alexa app, I can search for my skill, find it, and then I click "Enable".

Under "Authorization URL" I put:

https://alexa.salesvoiceapp.com/auth

(You might ask, why don't I go point straight to Salesforce? Well, I was hoping to harvest the Amazon user_id, so I went to my own server first. This was a failed idea.)

I've set this to "Implicit Grant".

When the user arrives on my server I harvest the Amazon user_id and then redirect to Salesforce:

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=URAx31ViKQovfPPXrCvi9CAfzsJJ8AtoACYEWqeB_IMxBQ&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Falexa.salesvoiceapp.com%2Fauth-callback&state=

And then in the Alexa app I see:

Not Found
The requested URL /&redirect_uri=https://alexa.salesvoiceapp.com/auth-callback was not found on this server

I believe that Amazon is causing this error? Or is this a SalesForce error?

Do I have to specify a "redirect_uri" as part of the URL? When I created my Connected App I specified this as the callback URL:

https://alexa.salesvoiceapp.com/auth-callback

Can I get SalesForce login to use that URL automatically, without me having to send it along as a parameter in the URL that I use to redirect users to SalesForce?

Answer (score 1):

OK, completely updating this with code.  Basically you need to add a header and transform the request, and the munge instance_url to the access token and add an expiry to the response.  Note this uses their Auth Code flow.

Here's the endpoint I use for the token URI, using Node + Express:

```
app.post('/token',function (req, res) {


console.log(req.body);
  var sr = sync_request('POST', 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
                      {
                      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept':'application/json'},
                      body: 'grant_type='+req.body.grant_type+'&code='+req.body.code+'&refresh_token='+req.body.refresh_token+'&client_id='+req.body.client_id+'&client_secret='+req.body.client_secret+'&redirect_uri='+req.body.redirect_uri
                      });
  console.log(sr.getBody('utf8'));
  response = JSON.parse(sr.getBody('utf8'));

  response.access_token = response.access_token + " " + response.instance_url;
  response.expires_in = 5400; //in seconds, set this to be less than your setting under session management.

  res.jsonp(response);
});
```

Then you can grab the token and instance url by splitting on the space.

[I've done a write up on using it](http://joshbirk.herokuapp.com/sf1-connecting-salesforce-with-amazons-auth-code-grant/), including the Amazon setup side.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to do it with the UI that amazon provides under the skills(Account Linking). Everything was perfectly set up and I was not able link my skill to SF via the connected app. I noticed that I had to provide scopes as `api` and `refresh_token`. It worked fine after that and I was able to link my SF account to my alexa skill.